# Gravar e Usar imagens em banco de dados ( Delphi e MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, delphi-xe6

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço pra gravar imagens (.jpg, .png, .bmp, etc) no banco de dados MySQL, usando o Delphi XE6.
Gostaria de usar o TDBImage, se possível, para mostrar as imagens já gravadas no banco de dados. Onde armazena a imagem no MySQL é do tipo *blob*.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, por experiência própria sugiro fortemente você salvar as imagens num diretório e salvar no banco de dados apenas o caminho do diretório. Salvar no banco de dados força o crescimento *desordenado* do banco, dificulta a manutenção, backups (*dumps*, por exemplo) entre outros empecilhos.
Porém, caso você queira ou precise seguir salvando no banco, seguem algumas alternativas de código:
`DBImage1.Picture.LoadFromFile('c:\pasta\imagem.jpg');`
ou (*Fonte:* https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/114397-resolvido-gravar-imagens-no-mysql/)

```
var
  MS :TMemoryStream;
begin
  ...
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    FOTO.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
    MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      FOTO.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(MS);
      (DataModule1.Table1.FieldByName('foto') as TBlobField).LoadFromStream(MS);
    finally
      MS.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Como já mencionado, `DBImage` é para **BMP´s**, como solução paliativa:

```
procedure TForm1.DBImage1DblClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  JPG:TJPEGImage; 
  BMP:TBitmap; 
begin 
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then 
  begin 
    JPG:= TJPEGImage.Create; 
    JPG.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName); 
    BMP:=TBitmap.Create; 
    BMP.Assign(JPG); 
    JPG.Free; 
    dbimage1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(BMP); 
    bmp.Free; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado Andrey, funcionou perfeitamente, porém, apenas grava imagens do tipo .bmp, outras imagens, por exemplo .jpg não são possíveis e também as imagens que já existem no banco (do tipo .jpg) não são exibidas no DBImage. ERRO: Bitmap image is not a valid.
Saberia como resolver isto? não sei dizer se é erro no DBImage, quando ele exibe o conteúdo do banco.

Comment: O que acontece é o que DbImage só funciona com bmp mesmo... com outras extensões é incompatível. Solução: *Gambiarra*. Vou editar a resposta com uma alternativa que consiste em carregar um jpg, mas convertê-lo para bmp para ser exibido no DbImage. Se a resposta respondeu a pergunta, lembre de aceita-la.

Comment: A solução seria converter antes de salvar no BD e salvá-lo como BMP já...